# Why is 'cryptsetup luksFormat' not prompting for a passphrase?

Tags: cryptsetup

I am expecting `cryptsetup` to prompt me for a passphrase, but instead it's just trying and failing to open a key file:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat test.img cryptsetup-test

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on test.img irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Failed to open key file.
```

Comment: The format you are attempting to use is `cryptsetup luksFormat <device> [<key file>]`,  therefore `cryptsetup-test` is being interpreted as a keyfile, which probably isn't what you want and doesn't exist, hence the error `Failed to open key file.`. A keyfile can be used instead of an interactive password.

Comment: For those who ended up reading this, but were not being asked for a passphrase after typing "yes" and the command exited quietly, but you expected a passphrase prompt, make sure the YES is upper case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the syntaxes for [`luksFormat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html#:%7E:text=luksFormat%20%3Cdevice%3E%20%5B%3Ckey%20file%3E%5D) and [`luksOpen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html#:%7E:text=luksOpen%20%3Cdevice%3E%20%3Cname%3E%20(old%20syntax)).

`luksFormat` does not open the device, so doesn't take a device name to map to.  So if you try to pass one, it will interpret it as a filename for a key file and try (and probably fail) to open it.

Here's what it should look like when you use each command:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat test.img
WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on test.img irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase:
Verify passphrase:
```

And an example of `luksOpen`:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen test.img cryptsetup-test
Enter passphrase for test.img
```